# stuck on login flow not able to move forward to org

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, login-errors, grant-login-access, loginflow

I created a login fl[image]ow and removed the Finish Button. so now i am stuck on login flow and not able to access the Org.

Answer (score 1):

So sad to hear this.

> Try deactivating the flow from VS code which you used in your login
> flow.

**OR**

The other thing you can do is -

In your VS Code retrieve the flow which you have created. You have to search for flow, not login flow. The flow which you have used in your Login flow. Just retrieve that. And you can search for tag -

```
<allowFinish>false</allowFinish>
```

and make it true.

And also make sure that tag

```
<showFooter>true</showFooter>
```

have true value. If false then make it true.

Comment: I can not able to find.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please try those steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the org via SFDX using this command.

```
sfdx auth:web:login --setalias orgalias --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com
```

Then use

```
sfdx force:org:open -u orgalias
```

This will escape login flow as it goes via SFDX.

Comment: I have taken both way to connect that org but can't Authorized.

Comment: What issue are you facing when using `sfdx auth:web:login`

Comment: Not able to login and getting same problem...